# I'm really stumped with this one. Not sure why my filter works in the console.log(filteredMovies) but not for displayMovies(filteredMovies)

Tags: javascript

**Not sure what the problem is**

The code works fine until I try and use the `filteredMovies` in the `displayMovies` function not sure what is going on here.

I am new to coding and am trying to get the API to work. Everything looks good until I get to this point. Not sure if there is another way to go about doing this or what I have to do to fix this but this has been very frustrating.

```
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
const url = 'https://yts.mx/api/v2/list_movies.json?sort_by=download_count&limit=25';

let ytxMovies = [];

const movies = 'movies';

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const searchString = e.target.value;
  const filteredMovies = ytxMovies.data.movies.filter((list_movies) => {
    return list_movies.title_english.includes(searchString);
  });
  console.log(filteredMovies);
  displayMovies(filteredMovies) // says movies on line 27 is undefined 
});

const loadMovies = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    ytxMovies = await res.json();
    displayMovies(ytxMovies);
    // console.log(ytxMovies);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

const displayMovies = (movie_list) => {
  // this is the only way to display all the movies
  const htlmString = movie_list.data.movies
    .map((movie_list) => {
      return `
    <li class="movie_list">
    <h2>${movie_list.title}
    <p>${movie_list.description_full}
    <img src="${movie_list.medium_cover_image}"></img>
    </li>
    `;
    })
    .join('');
  movieList.innerHTML = htlmString;
};

loadMovies();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're filtering the `ytxMovies.data.movies` in the `filteredMovies` so the `displayMovies` will get `ytxMovies.data.movies` when you pass it so, it doesn't have the `data.movies` when you `map` it!

### Solution:

Change `loadMovies` to this:

```js
const loadMovies = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(url)
        ytxMovies = await res.json()
        displayMovies(ytxMovies.data.movies)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

This way it will pass an array to the `displayMovies`, then change the `displayMovies` to:

```js
const displayMovies = (movie_list) => {
    // this is the only way to display all the movies
    const htlmString = movie_list
        .map((movie) => {
            return `
                <li class="movie">
                <h2>${movie.title}
                <p>${movie.description_full}
                <img src="${movie.medium_cover_image}"></img>
                </li>
                `
        })
        .join('')
    movieList.innerHTML = htlmString
}
```

I changed your `map` a bit in `displayMovies`, the whole code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="search-bar" type="search" />
        <ul id="movie-list">
            Loading
        </ul>
        <script>
            let searchBar = document.getElementById('search-bar')
            let movieList = document.getElementById('movie-list')
            const url =
                'https://yts.mx/api/v2/list_movies.json?sort_by=download_count&limit=25'
            let ytxMovies = []
            const movies = 'movies'
            searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
                const searchString = e.target.value
                const filteredMovies = ytxMovies.data.movies.filter((movie) =>
                    movie.title_english.includes(searchString)
                )
                displayMovies(filteredMovies)
                // says movies on line 27 is undefined
            })

            const loadMovies = async () => {
                try {
                    const res = await fetch(url)
                    ytxMovies = await res.json()
                    displayMovies(ytxMovies.data.movies)
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            }

            const displayMovies = (movie_list) => {
                // this is the only way to display all the movies
                const htlmString = movie_list
                    .map((movie) => {
                        return `
                <li class="movie">
                <h2>${movie.title}
                <p>${movie.description_full}
                <img src="${movie.medium_cover_image}"></img>
                </li>
                `
                    })
                    .join('')
                movieList.innerHTML = htlmString
            }

            loadMovies()
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```